# Back button override

Tags: java, webview

I have a web app where I use multiple web pages in the app.
For example, "`page1.html`", "`page2.html`". There is a link in page 1 to go to page 2, and from page 2, how do I get back to page 1 using the back button in mobile phone?

I have tried using the following code :

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
if (WebView.canGoBack()){
    WebView.goBack();
} else {
      super.onBackPressed();
}

}
}
```

And now, here it shows the following errors :

1.) Non-static method 'canGoBack()' cannot be referenced from a static context

2.) Non-static method 'goBack()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: How does your code relate to HTML pages?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I use webview in android studio